# JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) throwing error in hosted environment

Tags: c#, .net, iis, jwt, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 project. I am trying to generate a JWT within. This line is giving me an error deployed to an IIS web server: `JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)`

```
The encryption algorithm 'System.String' requires a key size of at least 'System.Int32' bits.
Key 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey', is of size: 'System.Int32'. (Parameter 'key')
```

There is commented code I have put in there to test that the values going into the token generation are OK, and the key is 16 characters long (I have tested with a lot more and still fails).

This works fine in my local environment.

Anyone know why this might be?

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
};

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtConfig.Value.SecretKey));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_jwtConfig.Value.Issuer,
    _jwtConfig.Value.Audience,
    claims,
    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
    signingCredentials: creds);

//return new JsonResult(new Dictionary<string, object>
//  {
//    { "secretkey", _jwtConfig.Value.SecretKey },
//    { "creds", creds.ToString() },
//    { "issuer", _jwtConfig.Value.Issuer },
//    { "audience", _jwtConfig.Value.Audience },
//    { "token", token.ToString() }
//  });


return new JsonResult(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      { "access_token", new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) },
    });
```

Relevant section from `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<JWTSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings"));

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

        var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:SecretKey").Value;
        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Issuer").Value,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Audience").Value,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

        };

    })
```

Comment: What's the value of _jwtConfig.Value.SecretKey? It seems that the value get from local environment. What's the length of secretKey in startup file? `var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey))`

Comment: Its longer than 16 chracters @BruceZhang as is necessaryu for the HmacSHA256, pulling from the `appsettings.json` file. When I uncomment the commented section (which I put in so I could see what it was pulling through) I could see it was the right value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have error [IDX10653](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/e2e64e5ce0f5d56a8c881885526079a7cdc0ce90/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/LogMessages.cs#L170).

But your exception message do not display real information. Please review this [article](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1498) for details. Could you add the code `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` and provide real exception message?

I think you will see real exception message and you can understand what happened.
Highly likely your `SecretKey` is less then 128 bits. In this case just try to use more long value for parameter `JWTSettings:SecretKey` in your configuration file. So similar scenario was described [here](https://codedocu.com/Details_mobile?d=2163&z=1&t=Error%20The%20algorithm%20HS256%20requires%20the%20SecurityKey.KeySize%20to%20be%20greater%20than%20128%20bits).

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be coding issue, more something on the .NET Configuration of the web host. Deploying the application as "Framework Dependent" results in the error, however "Self Contained" the code itself works.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I might have the solution but I'm not so sure so let me know if this works:

I've configured my JWT token directly in my Startup.cs like so:

Startup.cs

```
public static void AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<JwtSettings>(configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings"));

        // Identity stuff

        services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
        })
            .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", o =>
            {
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                o.SaveToken = true;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]))
                };

                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                    {
                        c.NoResult();
                        c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                        c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                        return c.Response.WriteAsync($"{c.Exception.ToString()} JwtBearerEvents in IdentityServiceRegistration");
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("401 Not authorized");
                        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                    },
                    OnForbidden = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("403 Not authorized");
                        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                    },
                };
            });
    }
```

And here's my token generation method used by CreateUserAsync and other methods:

```
private async Task<JwtSecurityToken> GenerateToken(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf,
                new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp,
                new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddYears(10))
                .ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString())
        }
        .Union(userClaims);

        var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            new JwtHeader(
                new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("//secret key of 64 characters of capital letters and numbers")),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)),
            new JwtPayload(claims));

        return jwtSecurityToken;
    }
```

You should be able to generate a key from a website like this: [SHA256 Generator](https://tools.keycdn.com/sha256-online-generator)

Let me know if it helps.